# Why is background-image not visible when child is hidden?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site with a hero image and I want to display the image differently depending on whether the user is on a mobile or desktop device.

When the user is on a desktop, I want the `img` element to display the image, but when the user is on a mobile device I want the `img` to be hidden and the `background-image` of the `img`'s container to display the image.

The issue I'm encountering is that when the `img` element becomes hidden, the `background-image` of the container is not visible either even though it's properly defined on the container element. I've tried troubleshooting this for so long but to no avail.

How would I fix this strange behavior?  I'm also open to any code improvements in terms of better practice if needed :) Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y34jog0r/1/) for reference.

HTML:

```html
<div class="header-image-wrapper container-fluid">
     <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/2c/2b/af2c2b231f5e8c168f32263842852065.png" class="hide-hero-img" alt="Some image"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.header-image-wrapper{
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/2c/2b/af2c2b231f5e8c168f32263842852065.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
    
    
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header-image-wrapper {
        background-image: url("https://www.kmuw.org/sites/kmuw/files/202009/SuperMario35.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -ms-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .hide-hero-img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's because when you hide the `img` element, the `.header-image-wrapper` now has no content and you don't specify any sizing properties (`width` and `height`) for the `.header-image-wrapper`, therefore its area is zero.

This is due to the way you hide the `img` element (with `display: none;`), which makes it take no space on the page. Instead you can make the `img` invisible with `opacity: 0;` and non-interactable with `pointer-events: none;`. This way the `img` is hidden, but its size, and therefore the size of its parent, is not altered.

Here's an example:

What you currently have:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

.image-wrapper img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img width="40" height="30"/>
</div>
```

Solution:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

.image-wrapper img {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img width="40" height="30"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I learned something new :D